# How to smooth a jagged SVG line in D3?

Tags: html, css, svg, d3.js, line

I am working in D3 and when I move lines around to diagonal positions they fragment into visible "steps", as shown in the picture below. Any suggestions for how I can create uniform, non-stepped, non-jagged lines in d3?  Thanks!

[Picture of Jagged Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMVlN.png)

I've tried setting CSS properties on the lines including `shape-rendering: crispEdges; stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-miterlimit: 2; and stroke-linecap: round`.  None of these has solved the problem.

Comment: `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` make it pixelated, try `shape-rendering: geometricprecision;`